# Can I build a Python function which can bounce back to any start point at when it was executed?

Tags: python, function

I was trying to make a game in which the main character can get into an arena at any time he want. But I want the story to be continued when the character back from the arena. How could realize it?

I'd like to make an arena function like example below:

```
def issue_a():
    input1 = raw_input('1:issue_b  2:arena'）
    if input1 == '1': 
        return issue_b
    elif input1 == '2':
        return arena

def issue_b():   
    input2 = raw_input('1:issue_c  2:arena'）
    if input2 == '1':
        return issue_c
    elif input2 == '2':
        return arena

def issue_c():
    pass

def arena():
    ???

issue_a()

# execute issue_a, I chose 2 first
# return arena
# !!!after arena executed, I need it back to input1!!!
# I chose 1 now, I went to issue_b
# I chose 2
# return arena
# !!!after arena executed, I need it back to input2 now!!!
# I chose 1 now, then I went to issue_c
```

---

Can I make an arena function met my requirement above with python?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `return` does? It's odd that you're returning the next function to call; while a program can be structured that way, what results is pretty close to [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) with a trampoline, which isn't the most natural or programmer-friendly way to do things. I'm not sure whether what you're doing is deliberate.

Comment: A function will always return to where it is called from.  I don't know if I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @user2357112,  I'm new to programming, and python is the first language I'm learning to use.

Comment: What you have might work better than the usual first attempt, which is to call the next function directly at the end of each function (and eventually get a stack overflow if the program runs long enough). I'm just wondering whether it's deliberate, because I haven't seen anyone do it like this before, and it's common to misunderstand `return` for a while until you get the hang of things.

Comment: @user2357112, I think you've misunderstand my purpose. I intended to let the player can acesses a complicate function called arena at any_time, each time he went to the arena, his attributes will have some change. function arena is a special one, it belongs to another system I intended to plant in this game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a parameter to the `arena` function to know which function after doing its stuff, like:

```
def issue_a():
    input1 = raw_input('1:issue_b  2:arena')
    if input1 == '1': 
        return issue_b
    elif input1 == '2':
        return arena(issue_a)

def issue_b():   
    input2 = raw_input('1:issue_c  2:arena')
    if input2 == '1':
        return issue_c
    elif input2 == '2':
        return arena(issue_b)

def issue_c():
    print "Game Over!"

def arena(back_to):
    print "doing arena stuff..."
    return back_to

# to let the arena function behave like the other functions, use this instead
#
# def arena(back_to):
#    def inner():
#        print "doing arena stuff..."
#        return back_to
#    return inner

func = issue_a
while func:
    func = func()
```

Comment: Oh, God. You are so brilliant, now I know what can parameters do in a function. You've solved two problems for me at the same time. You're my hero, bro.

Comment: Note that the `area` function is different from the other functions in the way that it gets executed inside `issue_a`/`issue_b` instead of inside the `while` loop directly. Keep that in mind. If that's a problem or if this bothers you, you can change the arena function to wrap an inner function. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A standard solution to this kind of problem is wrapping the outmost menu in a `while True` loop like so:

```
def issue_a():
    while True:
        input1 = raw_input('1:issue_b  2:arena'）
        if input1 == '1': 
            issue_b()
        elif input1 == '2':
            arena()

def issue_b():
    while True:
        input2 = raw_input('1:issue_c  2:arena  3: go back'）
        if input2 == '1':
            issue_c()
        elif input2 == '2':
            arena()
        elif input2 == '3':
            return

def issue_c():
    pass

def arena():
    pass

issue_a()
```

This way you will navigate around by responding to the input. When an action, like `arena` completes, you will be taken back to the previous function.